# SSH doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Here is what I see in syslog

```
Sep 18 01:01:16 homepage init: ssh main process ended, respawning
Sep 18 01:01:16 homepage init: ssh main process (1444) terminated with status 255
Sep 18 01:01:16 homepage init: ssh main process ended, respawning
Sep 18 01:01:16 homepage init: ssh main process (1447) terminated with status 255
Sep 18 01:01:16 homepage init: ssh main process ended, respawning
Sep 18 01:01:16 homepage init: ssh main process (1450) terminated with status 255
Sep 18 01:01:16 homepage init: ssh respawning too fast, stopped
```

The port in `sshd_config` is `22`, `ListenAddress` is commented

I got it when I tried to move `ssh` from `22` to `2222` port. Got it not worked and changed back, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

**UPD**:

I have no idea why it helped, but I just replaced `sshd_config` with one from backup. According to `diff` they were identical (didn't check `md5sum` though). And this helped :-S

**UPD2**:

it is `5.8p1-1ubuntu3`

Comment: Could you add your exact version number to your question for reference's sake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the fact that you are using Ubuntu, [this seems te be a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21801/ssh-server-not-working-respawns-until-stopped/22681#22681), as also indicated by the answers to this question on [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com):

Quoting original answer:

> This appears to be the result of bug #687535, which was fixed recently
>   in natty, and has been uploaded to both maverick and lucid as a
>   proposed update.
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/openssh/+bug/687535
>
> I'd encourage everyone to go there, try the test case (search for TEST
>   CASE), and post your results both before and after installing the
>   proposed fix. That will help the SRU team decide that verification has
>   been done and release it as an update.

Additionally, there seems to be at least one other person who has experienced the same problem and has successfully solved it by commenting the specific `ListenAddress` directive and adding a generic `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0`, as described in [this blog post](http://blog.roberthallam.org/2010/06/sshd-not-running-at-startup/):

> [....]
>
> My thinking is that sshd was trying to start up before the network
>   interfaces were configured, which was causing it to fail as it had a
>   ListenAddress directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
>
> Commenting out the specific ListenAddress directive and adding
>   ListenAddress 0.0.0.0 to let sshd listen on any address solved the
>   problem. The fileserver has only 1 IP address anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have sshd daemons running in the system

```
ps -ef | grep sshd
```

Kill any if there are.

Also make sure that no other process uses port 22

```
netstat -an | grep 22 | grep LISTEN
```

Then start sshd again (depends on system or distro you are using)